# Dynamic field validation in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This Is my Html Form by which i m creating a form and dynamic fields

```
<div style="margin:10px 0;color:#574F44;margin-left:160px;">
    <form name="frmsignup3" method="post" action="new_user2.php" style="margin-top:0px; line-height:60px;" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm2()" >
        <input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $_POST['user_name']?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_email" value="<?php echo $_POST['user_email']?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_pass" value="<?php echo $_POST['user_pass']?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_gen" value="<?php echo $_POST['user_gen']?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_dob_m" value="<?php echo $_POST['user_dob_m']?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_dob_d" value="<?php echo $_POST['user_dob_d']?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_dob_y" value="<?php echo $_POST['user_dob_y']?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_ili" value="<?php echo $_POST['user_ili']?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_pc" value="<?php echo $_POST['user_pc']?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_prof" value="<?php echo $_POST['user_prof']?>" />

        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">Specialities:</label>
        <input id="l" type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style="width:auto;" name="user[]"/>
        <!---------Dyanmic Fields  for specialities---------->
        <div id="add_user" style="display: none;"><label id="l" style="width:80px;">&nbsp;</label><input id="l"  class="l"type="text" size="37" style="width:auto;" name="user[]" value="" /></div>
        <input type="button" id="add_user()" onclick="add_user('add_user')" value="Add More!" /><br>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <!---------Dyanmic Fields ---------->

        <label id="l" style="width:120px;">Employment History:</label>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">Role:</label>
        <input id="l" type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style="width:auto;" name="user_role[]"/>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">Company:</label>
        <input id="l" type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style="width:auto;" name="user_com[]"/>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">From:</label>
        <input id="datepicker"  class="l" type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style="width:auto;" name="user_from[]"/>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">To:</label>
        <input id="datepicker1" class="l" type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style="width:auto;" name="user_to[]"/>
        <br class="clear"/>

        <!---------Dyanmic Fields for employment history---------->
        <div id="add_user1" style="display: none;" >
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">Role:</label><input id="l" type="text" size="37" style="width:auto;" name="user_role[]" value="" /><br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">Company:</label><input id="l" type="text" size="37" style="width:auto;" name="user_com[]" value="" /><br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">From:</label><input class="datepicker"  type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style=":Arial;font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;color:#7c7b77;outline: none;border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;margin:3px 5px;padding:8px 0;padding-left:5px;-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c7c7c7;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c7c7c7;box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c7c7c7;float:left;border-radius: 5px;" name="user_from[]" /><br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">To:</label><input class="datepicker" type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style=":Arial;font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;color:#7c7b77;outline: none;border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;margin:3px 5px;padding:8px 0;padding-left:5px;-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c7c7c7;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c7c7c7;box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c7c7c7;float:left;border-radius: 5px;" name="user_to[]"/><br class="clear"/></div>
        <input type="button" id="add_user1()" onclick="add_user1('add_user1')" name="btn" value="Add More!" /><br>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <!---------Dyanmic Fields ---------->

        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">Qualification:</label>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">Degree:</label>
        <input id="l" type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style="width:auto;" name="user_quli[]"/>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">Institute:</label>
        <input id="l" type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style="width:auto;" name="user_ins[]"/>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">From:</label>
        <input id="datepicker2" class="l" type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style="width:auto;" name="user_qfrom[]"/>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">To:</label>
        <input id="datepicker3" class="l" type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style="width:auto;" name="user_qto[]"/>
        <br class="clear"/>

        <!---------Dyanmic Fields for education---------->
        <div id="add_user2" style="display: none;">
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">Degree:</label><input id="l" type="text" size="37" style="width:auto;" name="user_quli[]" value="" /><br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">Institute:</label><input id="l" type="text" size="37" style="width:auto;" name="user_ins[]" value="" /><br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">From:</label><input  class="datepicker"  type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style=":Arial;font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;color:#7c7b77;outline: none;border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;margin:3px 5px;padding:8px 0;padding-left:5px;-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c7c7c7;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c7c7c7;box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c7c7c7;float:left;border-radius: 5px;" name="user_qfrom[]" /><br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">To:</label><input class="datepicker"  type="text" size="37" onblur="" value="" style=":Arial;font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;color:#7c7b77;outline: none;border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;margin:3px 5px;padding:8px 0;padding-left:5px;-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c7c7c7;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c7c7c7;box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c7c7c7;float:left;border-radius: 5px;" name="user_qto[]"/><br class="clear"/></div>
        <input type="button" id="add_user2()" onclick="add_user2('add_user2')" value="Add More!" /><br>
        <br class="clear"/> 
        <!---------Dyanmic Fields ---------->
        <!--Error Div-->
        <div  id="errorcv" style="display: none"> 

        </div>  
        <!--Error Div-->               
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">Upload CV:</label>
        <input id="l" type="file" size="37"  style="width:auto;" name="user_cv" onblur="return checkcv('user_cv')" accept="application/msword"/>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <!--Error Div-->
        <div  id="errorimg" style="display: none"> 
        </div>  
        <!--Error Div-->
        <label id="l" style="width:80px;">Upload Image:</label>
        <input id="l" type="file" size="37"  style="width:auto;" name="user_img" onblur="return checkPhoto('user_img')" accept="image/*"/>
        <br class="clear"/>
        <label id="l" style="width:80px; margin-left:90px; margin-right:15px;"><a href="" >Skip this step</a></label>
        <input type="image" src="<?php echo DIR_PATH?>images/btn_next.gif" alt=""/>
        <br class="clear"/>
    </form>
```

This is my javascript by which I am generating dynamic fields. Now I want to validate that dynamicaly generated  fields

```
var counter = 0;
function add_user(FieldName) {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById(FieldName).cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }

    var insertHere = document.getElementById(FieldName);
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}

var counter = 0;
function add_user1(FieldName) {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById(FieldName).cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById(FieldName);
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
    $(newFields).find('.datepicker').datepicker();

}

var counter = 0;
function add_user2(FieldName) {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById(FieldName).cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById(FieldName);
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
    $(newFields).find('.datepicker').datepicker();
}
```

I want to validate dynamic created text fields.

Comment: Seriously, dude - what can be explained by a single div doesn't need your entire source code. Please reduce the size of your posted code so that we can focus on what is relevant. Now, what do you mean by "validate"?

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee Chatterjee i want yo validaye that the fields are dynamicly creating can not be submited blank!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have different type fields. So when you add new fields add same class to every different type. Then you can easily put up validator function before post to chekc all types like this:

```
function your_validator() {
var passed = true;
$('.Specialities').each(function(){
 var current = $.trim($(this).val());
 if (your_false_condition) passed = false;//chekc specialiti value if its not ok
});

if (passed == false) {
alert('error');
return false;
}
return true;
}
```